# «Захватывали дух» — фразеологизм?

Tags: фразеология

«*Отсутствие всякой логики и высокомерие этой позиции просто захватывали дух.*»

Можно ли так поступать с фразеологизмом? Само предложение может существовать?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, фразеологизм - "дух захватывает",он отражает психическое состояние, предложение безличное. "Захватывали дух" - трансформированный фразеологизм.

```
    Можно ли так поступать с фразеологизмом? Само предложение может существовать?
```

Может, но только в **разговорной** речи. Различные преобразования фразеологизмов -излюбленный прием в текстах современных СМИ. Возможность  трансформации вытекает из сохранения у фразеологизмов внутренней формы, т.е. их исходного, буквального смысла, и относительной устойчивости. Преобразованиям могут быть подвергнуты как семантика, так и структура словосочетаний. Трансформация семантики фразеологизмов возможна потому, что они обладают внутренней формой, что позволяет авторам «реставрировать» в той или иной степени стершийся образ и приспособить обобщенный, метафорический смысл того или иного выражения к конкретным условиям контекста.

Это аналитическая трансформация,она, в отличие от семантической, вносит изменения в словесный состав фразеологизма. Она более разнообразна по своим приемам и сводится к нескольким основным типам: изменение количества компонентов, синтаксическая трансформация, лексическая трансформация, контаминация, фразеологическая парономазия.

У нас синтаксическая трансформация. Безличное предложение заменено на двусоставное, а общий смыл не изменился: дух захватывает = дыхание перехватило от изумления = отсутствие логики и высокомерие изумили(поразили) = отсутствие логики и высокомерие вызвали состояние изумления = отсутствие логики и высокомерие  захватили дух(прервали дыхание). Это же разговорный фразеологизм, а с разговорной конструкцией вообще обращаются довольно свободно.
При синтаксической трансформации может происходить замена видов синтаксической связи: «в тесноте и в обиде». Наибольшая выразительность достигается тогда, когда изменяется роль члена предложения, например, определение превращается в сказуемое, как в приводимых ниже заголовках: «Броня крепка, и танки - наши»; «Россия - Украина: самое синее в мире Черное море - мое!».

«Как развязать язык?» (обзор летних языковых школ для детей) [«МК №75, 7.04.08, с.9] Преобразование фразеологизма «язык развязывается».

Comment: Трудно согласиться, что «захватило дух» синонимично прерванному дыханию — «прервало дыхание». Дух не есть дыхание, захватить — совсем не прервать. Согласен только с определением «Развязать язык» как тренда на пути смены одного смысла другим.

Comment: @shampar  - БТС: Дух 5.Разг. (обычно в устойчивых сочет.). Дыхание. Д. захватывает. Д. замирает. Перевести д.

Comment: Не глядя скажу, что и «захватывать» — не выше 5-го значения у «прерывать». Значит (по уму), что трансформация на синоним не тянет.

Comment: Насколько сильно разговорный язык может отклоняться от нормы? Теоретически, конечно, насколько угодно (лишь бы собеседники понимали друг друга). Но я бы всё-таки расценивал, например, вариант "ложи сюда гитару" как грубую ошибку, а не просто старый добрый "разговорный стиль". Так же и пример в вопросе: "мой дух захватила его наглость" - на мой взгляд, грубая грамматическая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Как может отсутствие логики захватить дух... Да и "высокомерие позиции" не говорят. Очень неряшливая фраза.

Comment: Это же разговорный фразеологизм, — так решила Людмила и на этом основании «позволяет» его трансформировать. Понимаю Niemand: это принять трудно: у одних захватывает дух от громадья планов, у других — от отсутствия логики. Растём над собой.

Comment: Трансформация ни при чём. Не может "захватывать дух" от чего-то "плохого". Так мы не говорим. Ошибка примерно такая же, как в "Благодаря урагану город остался без света".

Comment: Очевидно, автор восхищен "отсутствием всякой логики и высокомерием этой позиции" :)

Comment: Высокомерие - качество личности или ее поведение, но никак не характеристика позиции.

Answer (score 1):

"Захватывать дух" требует все-таки положительной или нейтральной причины или коннотации. Захватывает дух от счастья, высоты, красоты. Это главное. "От высокомерия" - это какая-то фигура речи.

Остальное не слишком важно. Хотя безличная форма (дух захватывает - "от чего?") более естественна, но можно и личную употребить (дух захватывает -"что?"), нет ошибки.

Почему у автора дух захватывает от высокомерия, это его личное дело. Стиль у него такой.

Comment: Захватывать дух (прерывать дыхание) может буквально, физически, без всякой связи с эмоциями. Например, от сильного мороза, от быстрой езды.

Comment: @Хан может. А я разве против? У меня написано: *"требует все-таки положительной или **нейтральной причины или **коннотации***".

Answer (score 1):

Само-то предложение *уже* существует. Вопрос в другом: насколько оно верно?

*Отсутствие всякой логики и высокомерие этой позиции просто захватывали дух*.
[**косовский прецедент** (6 абзац)](http://mixednews.ru/archives/119416)

**дух захватило**
***дух захватывает/захватило*** *Разг.* Тяжело, трудно дышать (от избытка чувств, сильных переживаний, ощущений и т. п.).
*Мало-помалу я стала приходить в отчаяние, у меня дух захватывало **от горя.***
(Ф. Достоевский.)
*От рассказов этих о темных ночах, о лосях, о берлогах, о медведях дух захватывало.*
(В. Астафьев.)
[**Учебный фразеологический словарь**](http://phraseologiya.academic.ru/337)

*Не может "захватывать дух" от чего-то "плохого".*
Может: от горя, от страха, ***от несправедливости и нахальства***(в статье), от боли... - от сильных переживаний и ощущений, которые не всегда положительны.

**ВЫСОКОМЕРНЫЙ** *(книжн.)*. Полный высокомерия. Высокомерный человек. || *Обнаруживающий, выражающий высокомерие. **Высокомерный вид.***
(значение слова по словарю Ушакова)

*Его бесконечно разочаровывала **высокомерная позиция** Германии, которая по-прежнему не желала видеть...*
[**Юрий Сушко**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5T5kAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT147&lpg=PT147&dq=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=38Q9CdUUDJ&sig=IHVZQBE0gH5TeGq4b173w-2gU9c&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd4PPp8aTUAhXFA5oKHV_NAkI4ChDoAQgoMAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&f=false)

Лавров: *Отстранение курдов от переговоров по Сирии — это **высокомерная позиция** Турции.*

*Я богат(+), ты беден(-) (снобистская, **высокомерная позиция**).*
[**Эрик Берн**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=mPlPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=3IbEycz0-t&sig=B-Nm4DjGi4GQW5iyYyKfpeCPZDY&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYldKB46TUAhVqJ5oKHSgNCcYQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&f=false)

**"Захватывали дух"** используется очень часто, причем, с разными оттенками:

*Их акробатические номера, выполненные без какой-либо страховки, захватывали дух.*
*Ее «смертельные пике» с 4000 до 200 футов и головокружительные перевороты захватывали дух и собирали полные трибуны.*
*Трассы, созданные альпинистами, просто захватывали дух.*

Мне кажется, что все допустимо в предложении, в том числе и преобразованный фразеологизм.

Comment: Разговор, и это главное, — об изначальном фразеологизме как безличном и утрате им важнейшего свойства при трансформации (см. у Людмила, там же и о диагнозе). Переключение метафоры на прозаичную конкретику (номера, трассы захватывали) приводят к снижению уровня бывшего универсального фразеологизма до медицинского факта. ======== За определённостью мнения обоснования не разглядел. А именно: почему разговорности надо открыть двери в печать. Может быть оно там, где про частотность... Всё остальное... А с Достоевским и Астафьевым полный порядок, никакой трансформации.

Comment: Я пыталась объять сразу три вопроса. 1. Не может "захватывать дух" от чего-то "плохого". Может. 2. "Имеет ли право на жизнь" понятие "высокомерная позиция"? Имеет. 3. «Захватывали дух» — фразеологизм? Да. Изменения по схеме: дух захватывает - дух захватывали -  захватывали дух.

Comment: Первые два — не мои вопросы. А как изменили фразеологизм, и чем по ходу подменили, мы тут вместе разобрались.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще с фразеологизмами можно "поступать" очень разнообразно, здесь я согласен с Людмилой.

Не совсем согласен насчёт "современных СМИ":

```
Кричу благим (а не просто) матом...

За восемь бед - один ответ. 
В тюрьме есть тоже лазарет...

Когда провалишься сквозь землю от стыда
Иль поклянешься:«Провалиться мне на месте!» —
Без всяких трудностей ты попадешь сюда (- к антиподам i.e.)...
```

И да, не согласен ещё с ответом на второй вопрос: само предложение в вопросе не должно существовать, в данном конкретном случае фразеологизм разрушен необратимо, смысл искажён до неузнаваемости (субъект не может "перехватить чьё-то дыхание"). Это звучит, как... ну, например, как "подъезжая к лесу, с меня слетела шляпа". Как обычная грамматическая ошибка.

Comment: Согласен, хотя "поступать" очень разнообразно надобно не разрушая.

Answer (score 1):

**Правильный вариант:** От отсутствия всякой логики и высокомерия этой позиции у него просто захватывало дух.

Чем это предложение хуже предложенного, а оно соответствует норме.

**Дух захватывает, захватило, занимает, заняло у кого-л., от чего-л.** — тяжело дышать от избытка сильных переживаний, каких-л. ощущений и т.п. — После нескольких звуков... все будто плыло и неслось мимо него в воздушном пространстве. И он, казалось ему, все рос выше, у него занимало дух. Гончаров.

[ДУХ | frazeologiya.ru](http://www.frazeologiya.ru/fraza/duh.htm)

Comment: Отличная редакция. Не понимаю, кто мешал безымянному переводчику также грамотно изъясняться.